# success de ajax no ejecuta

Tags: laravel, ajax

estoy con un problemita que no doy como resolver: tengo un formulario que proceso via ajax (en este form hago subida de imagenes), sube las imagenes y guarda bien en la base de datos, pero requiero que en el success del ajax se ejecuten una serie de acciones:

1. Que se oculte el formulario de carga de las imagenes
2. Que se desbloqueé un boton que antes del submit tengo bloqueado

El problema es que por mas que hace todo bien, lo que tengo dentro del submit no se ejecuta nunca... Ai tengo el codigo en la vista:

```
  <!--UPLOAD IMAGENES-->
                        <div class="col-lg-12" id="imagenes">
                         <h6 class="text-center">IMAGENES DEL MANTENIMIENTO</h6>
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="btnRegistrarImagenes">Seleccionar Imagenes</a>
                            <br>
                            <div class="exitoImagen">se cargaron las imagenes</div>
                            <div id="formularioFinalImagenes">
                            <form id="formImagenes" action="javascript:void(0)" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                 @csrf
                                 <input type="hidden" name="mantenimiento_id_img" id="mantenimiento_id_img" value="{{$mantenimiento->id}}" class="form-control" readonly>
                            <div id="tablaImagenesDiv">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btnAgregarFilaImagen"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Agregar Nueva Foto</a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="btnEliminarFilaImagen"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i> Eliminar Foto</a>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <table class="table table-bordered" id="tblImagenes">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>

                                            <th scope="col" style="width: 40%">Archivo Seleccionado</th>
                                            <th scope="col" style="width: 50% ;">Titulo/Comentario</th>
                                            </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                    </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                                              <button type="submit" id ="btnSubir" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> Subir Imagen(es)</button>

                        </div>
                        <br>
                    </div>

                  
                    </form>
                        </div>
```

el codigo ajax que hace el subimit del form:

```
//SUBMIT FORM IMAGENES
$('#formImagenes').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var formData = new FormData(this);
let TotalFiles = $('#imagen')[0].files.length; //Total files
let files = $('#imagen')[0];
for (let i = 0; i < TotalFiles; i++) {
formData.append('files' + i, files.files[i]);
}
formData.append('TotalFiles', TotalFiles);
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url: "{{ url('sistema/mantenimientos/ejecuciones/images')}}",
data: formData,
cache:false,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
dataType: 'json',
success: (data) => {
this.reset();
$('.exitoImagen').show();
            console.log("aca deberia desbloquear el boton de guardar y ocultar el formulario de carga de iamgenes")
              $(".btn-guardar").prop('disabled', false);

}
});
});
```

En el controlador tengo así la función para guardar las imágenes:

```
public function store(Request $request){


       $idejecucion = $request->get('mantenimiento_id_img');

       $ejecucion = EjecucionMantenimiento::where('id',$idejecucion)->first();

        if($request->hasFile('imagen')){
            foreach ($request->file('imagen') as $key => $value) {
                $image_name = $value->getClientOriginalName();
                $value->storeAs('fotos', $image_name);
                $projectImages = new ImagenesMantenimiento();
                $projectImages->imageable_id = $idejecucion;
                $projectImages->ruta = 'fotos/'.$image_name;
                $projectImages->imageable_type = $idejecucion;
                $projectImages->comentario = $request->get('comentario')[$key];
                $projectImages->save();
            }
            return back()->with('success', 'La Imagen se ha subido correctamente...');
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema parece estar en la función de éxito del AJAX. Estás utilizando una función de flecha (arrow function), lo que hace que el contexto de `this` no sea el mismo que el del formulario. Para solucionar esto, puedes cambiar la función de flecha por una función regular y almacenar una referencia al formulario antes del llamado AJAX. Aquí tienes el código modificado:

```javascript
$('#formImagenes').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    let TotalFiles = $('#imagen')[0].files.length; //Total files
    let files = $('#imagen')[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < TotalFiles; i++) {
        formData.append('files' + i, files.files[i]);
    }
    formData.append('TotalFiles', TotalFiles);

    // Almacenar referencia al formulario
    var form = this;

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: "{{ url('sistema/mantenimientos/ejecuciones/images')}}",
        data: formData,
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) { // Cambiar a función regular
            form.reset(); // Usar la referencia al formulario
            $('.exitoImagen').show();
            console.log("aca deberia desbloquear el boton de guardar y ocultar el formulario de carga de iamgenes")
            $(".btn-guardar").prop('disabled', false);
            // Ocultar el formulario de carga de imágenes
            $('#formularioFinalImagenes').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Con este cambio, la función de éxito debería ejecutarse correctamente y desbloquear el botón y ocultar el formulario de carga de imágenes.

Comment: toda la razon estimado, muchas gracias